# JAX-RS on Tomcat by using RestEasy

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs, resteasy, tomcat9

I'm new to the REST application by using the JAX-RS standard and I want to learn how to work with this standard.
So I downloaded and setup Apache Tomcat 9.0 and I added the `<Context>`
like this:

```
<Context docBase="...\RestEasyApp\target\RestEasyApp" path="/example" reloadable="true"/>
```

Then with `Maven` I created my project that have this structure:
[image]

Then into the `pom.xml` i added **RestEasy** by this dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-servlet-initializer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then into the `web.xml` I created the Servlet and it looks like this:

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
      </listener-class>
   </listener>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Then finally i created the Hello.java class that will handle the request and it looks like this:

```
package com.pisi.resteasyapp;

import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/api")
class Hello {

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "HELLO";
    }

}
```

But when I run this App with this uri `http://localhost:8080/example/rest/api/hello` , it gives me this:
[image]

I have no clue why it wont work.

Comment: Try changing @Path("/api") with @Path("/rest/api")

Comment: @RobertHume, no it doesn't work

Comment: Please, see my answer, I tested it right now; I hope it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add an `Application` class to your project:

```
package com.pisi.resteasyapp;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(new Hello());
        return set;
    }

}
```

You have also to change the mapping of the `Hello`class from `@Path("/api")` to `@Path("/rest/api")` and make the class `public` to allow RESTEasy to reflect on the `hello()` method:

```
@Path("/rest/api")
public class Hello {
```

In general, a better solution would be:

1. remove the `<servlet-mapping>` from `web.xml`
2. change `@ApplicationPath("")` to `@ApplicationPath("/rest")` in the `HelloApplication` class
3. use `@Path("/api")` instead of `@Path("/rest/api")` in the `Hello` class

Comment: With this kind of approach it gives me this Tomcat Error https://imgur.com/a/eMQVikX

Comment: @Pisi please verify that your Context docBase configuration is right, in particular you can try to specify an absolute path (i.e. c:/path/to/target/target/RestEasyApp)

Comment: the docBase of Context is "C:\Users\Filippo\Desktop\Heroku\RestEasyApp\target\RestEasyApp" that is absolute

Comment: have you tried to produce a war and put it into tomcat/webapps directly? I would like to understand if this is a deploy issue or not.

Comment: it isn't a deploy error, because it give me the same error also if i deploy the .war

Comment: Sorry, I don't know your Tomcat configuration. I downloaded Tomcat 9 right now, unpacked it in a folder, then I built the war (`mvn clean package`), renamed it as "example.war", copied it from `target` into `tomcat/webapps`, started Tomcat, and it works.

Comment: if you want to check it more easly, I pushed the project on GitHib https://github.com/iPisi/RestEasyApp I hope that will help you figure out the problem

Comment: You have a misspelled folder in your project: `reasteasyapp` should be `resteasyapp` to match the `package` declarations. Let's begin fixing this.

Comment: Ok I fixed the name and updated the GitHub repo,  but it gives me the same 404

Comment: Ok, please remove that `<init-param>` from `web.xml` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! it works! just out of curiosity now that i have deleted <init-param> tag, the HelloApplication class i no longer needed?

Comment: You're welcome. The `HelloApplication` is needed and it is autodetected thanks to Servlet 3.0 and the `@ApplicationPath` annotation.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark my answer as "correct" if you want. Thanks.